# Problem Naming an Interface

Tags: language-agnostic, naming

I have an interface named `PropertyFilter` which used to take a `Property`and decide if accepts it or not. And the world was good.

But now the interface changed, so that implementations may choose to add additional  `Property`s. For example a `Customer` property might get expanded into `Name` and `Address` properties.

I think it is obvious this is not a Filter anymore, but how would you call such a thing?

To clarify: the so called filter is pretty much a method with the signature

```
Property -> List<Property>
```

With an empty List denoting not accepting the Property, a List with exactly the input Property denoting accepting the property and a List with new Properties (possibly including the original one) denoting an expansion.

Comment: Still seems like a filter to me.  A `Filter[T]` is usually some function `T -> Boolean` which this still seems to be.

Comment: Why do you care about Property in the PropertyFilter? Why not simply having a Filter interface?

Comment: @mathk We choose PropertyFilter over Filter because there are already two Filters in our code base and about a gazillion in the library we use. But the question is really about the Filter part of the name.

Comment: @Travis I updated the question to show that the declaration we have does not match the expected declaration of a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PropertyChecker
- PropertyValidator
- PropertyDistillator
- PropertyAccreditor
  ...

Do you already have a name for the method you mention ? It might help us find a proper name for the interface as well.

Comment: the method is currently called 'expand'

Comment: OK, so the interface has a mixed responsibility of validating and expanding properties. You might use a more general name like PropertyManager or PropertyHandler.

Or, you might split the 2 responsibilities in 2 separate classes, PropertyValidator and PropertyExpander with one calling the other.

I guess the solution depends on how client code uses the interface, and on whether client code is aware of the validation aspect or expansion aspect (or both).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your new function does.  If it still returns a boolean, then another name for a function which returns a boolean value is a "predicate".

If it takes a Customer and decomposes it (perhaps you have one function which takes a Customer and returns a Name, and another which returns an Address), then I might call them "accessors".  This term is often used to describe a member function of an object, but I think it could apply here, too.

Comment: See my updated question, predicate doesn't fit, I I don't think accessors fits ...

Answer (score 0):

If `Customer` has a `Name` and and `Address`, the it is no longer a *property*, but an *entity*.

The `Customer` property could be a *reference* to a `Customer` entity, in which case the semantic convention for your interface still apply.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a method named `validate` to `Property` with the signature:

```
PropertyFilter -> Bool
```

The default implementation of `validate` simply passes `this` (the Property) to the filter and returns the result:

```
def validate (filter: PropertyFilter) = filter (this)
```

As a compound property, `Customer` overrides `validate`, implementing it in terms of its composite properties:

```
override def validate (filter: PropertyFilter) = name.validate (filter) && address.validate (filter)
```

This way, each `Property` can describe how to apply any given `PropertyFilter` to itself. I think you should avoid the List expansion approach.